# Is touches a method of NSSET class, if yes but it is not listed as method under NSSET reference documentation

Tags: ios7, cocos2d-iphone

Hi Im very new to programming and cocos 2d,

I'm following along with video tutorial from lynda.com.

The author wrote following code

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CCLOG(@"touch happened");
}
```

although it works fine, but i need help understanding touches, xcode code hinting states it is derived from NSSET class however when i try to look it up NSSET reference documentation, touches is not listed anywhere although i can see "anyobject" method but not touches.

I want to know how does this hierarchy work, since author pointed it out i know but was wondering how would i go about finding such methods

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSSet is a collection class, similar to NSArray and NSDictionary. Which means you can put other objects in it.

In this case NSSet contains UITouch objects. As indicated by:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
```

This returns any object from the set. Usually it's just the one touch, but it could really be any if there are multiple UITouch objects in the set.

Long story short you need to look at the [UITouch reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html).